# Data recovery site mesaures

Tags: iis, cluster-computing, data-recovery

our ASP.Net application is currently deployed over the farm with the below specs:

- 2 web front end servers controlled by an NLB
- 1 Application server hosting windows services and a workflow engine
- An Active/Passive SQL Server cluster

we are required to provide a specific strategy to deploy a Data recovery site. is there any specific measures or configuration to be considered in such a farm or just adapt a replica of the whole farm.
including (IIS sites,services,SQL databases...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always there are a number of ways in which you can provide disaster recovery for your solution.

1. You could use you SAN to replicate in real-time (assuming you have VMs setup for your primary site) data written.
2. You could do some form of log shipping at the database level and have a cold spare setup mirroring the primary configuration.
3. Add another NLB web server and move your passive SQL server to your DR site, although deepening on the data centre latency may be an issue.

My preference would be option 1 however it will depend on the exact business need, cost and risk to the business in needing DR.